# Codename One Sidemenu is Missing content when in permanent mode

Tags: java, codenameone

I've got a [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) application that has a heavily customized side menu based on the old `SideMenuBar`. After noticing the blog post covering the ability to have a [permanent sidemenu](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/permanent-sidemenu-getAllStyles-scrollbar-and-more.html) with the `Toolbar` code I migrated my code to the new `Toolbar` API.

The code is pretty similar and works rather well however when I switch to the permanent side menu mode some elements are missing. E.g. :

```
Command sep = new Command("");
sep.putClientProperty(new Label(" ", "Separator"));
toolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(sep);
```

Shows a separator perfectly but doesn't work when permanent side menu is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was behavior that worked for the `SideMenuBar` but we didn't keep that behavior as we migrated to the `Toolbar` API.

You can use `addComponentToSidemenu` instead.